# SharePoint 2013 - “Package failed” error while creating the web parts in vs 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am using SharePoint 2013 server and vs 2010. My SharePoint server present in different server and vs 2010 is another PC. I have created test web part using vs 2010 and build successfully. When I click on "Package", I am getting the error as "Package failed". Also I am not able to generated the .wsp file in bin folder. Can any one help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio development environment has to be in the same server as your development Sharepoint server instance.  You can Not develop remotely with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. But I do not want to install the vs on SharePoint 2013 server PC as i have some limitations. Can you help me if there is any other way to get this out?